# Getting Error(Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found) While running project

Tags: android, android-studio

i am getting this error while developing my app, every thing works fine suddenly this error happened while run the app and checking the changes, as i told everything works fine suddenly this happen i didn't change anything in Manifest.xml file[.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wsB6.png), this is the manifest file kindly help me out.

[this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGpt0.png)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.habitreminder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".OnboardingPackage.OnboardingSlider"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".userhome.UserDashboardActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_dashboard">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".signup.UserCalenderSignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".signup.UserMapSignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".signup.UserDetailsSignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginSignup.LoginSignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCy-z3OoXACHh_MKBLoCPjdNo2ySD1ogU8" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileSettings.changeprofilename"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemepopup"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: share your manifest.xml please .

Comment: Please first try to google about that error. I'm sure you will get so many same questions and solutions for that. For, error there is some issue with your manifest file.

Comment: @dariush i have posted my manifest, kindly look into this please.

Comment: @manishKarena Already search each and every single site, not resolve the error yet

Comment: @AmeerHamzaKhan I think you should add those thing that what you have reviewed and tried so far so reviewer of the question can get more idea about the issue. And second thing please remove the manifest code that you have posted in your answer, you should post it into your question. I know you are newbie to SO and this is how we help each other and learn new things :)

Comment: @ManishKarena edit the code as you said kindly look into my manifest file if you get    something.

Comment: Thank You so much for all your support, the issue has been removed i am posting the answer below which helps me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your activity declared in َAndroidManifest like this ?

```css
<activity
            android:name=".launchactivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJK8.png)
I just close the Android Studio And delete 2 folders name caches and tmp and start the Android Studio again and it worked.